# Referenced yarn workspace types are not recognized by tsc, but they work on VS Code

Tags: typescript, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I have a monorepo where I have two workspaces using TypeScript, /ui and /graphql

/ui references /graphql, and VS Code can fetch the types from it, add imports, autocomplete properties, etc.
But when I try to do `tsc --build` for /ui it throws errors about not finding the module for the imports:

Here's the tsconfig for /graphql:

```
{
  "extends": "../../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "outDir": "build",
    "rootDir": "src"
  },

  "include": ["**/*.tsx", "**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["build"]
}
```

here's the base tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "incremental": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "preserveWatchOutput": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,

    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "packages/*": ["packages/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["*node_modules", "**/*.test.ts*"]
}
```

and here is the /ui tsconfig:

```
{
  "extends": "../../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "composite": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "outDir": "build",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
      "@/config": ["src/config.ts"],
      "@/components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "@/assets/*": ["src/assets/*"]
    }
  },
  "types": [
    "jest",
    "@types/testing-library__react",
    "@types/testing-library__jest-dom",
    "node"
  ],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../graphql"
    }
  ],
  "exclude": ["build"],
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Everything seems to be in order, especially when using VS Code since everything works when it comes to TypeScript features.

Running `tsc --build` on the /graphql repo passes without errors (even if there is no output due to the tsconfig, also tried adding outFile to no avail).

But when I run `tsc --build` or `tsc -p tsconfig.json` on the /ui package, I get errors like:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module '@goe/graphql'. '[...]/packages/frontend/graphql/build/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Seems i might have stumbled upon the solution by reading my question, the part of the error saying that index.js was of type any made me thing that maybe i just needed to emit types with the same name, so i just changed the graphql tsconfig to

```
{
  "extends": "../../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true, // this option alone to emit types next to each compiled file
    "noEmit": false,
    "outDir": "build",
    "rootDir": "src"
  },
  "include": ["**/*.tsx", "**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["build"]
}
```

and now the tsc build on /ui works :)

Comment: I faced with same error. Can u help me pls? I'm also using workspaces